# The Node Package Manager (NPM) seems to yield duplicated packages

Tags: node.js, module, npm

I've been installing a few node packages and what I noticed is that NPM creates a bunch of duplicates.

For example, I first installed mongoose, which installed a bunch of dependencies, naturally. Then I installed the mongodb package, which also came with bson as a dependency. Due to overlapping dependencies, I have the following anomaly:

Mongodb is present in the following directories:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mongodb/
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/
```

Also, bson, a dependency of mongodb is present in both of these:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mongodb/
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/
```

I realize these are only files of kilobytes, but I feel like this might create a lot of redundancy end I might end up with a very complex tree similar to the following:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/[something1]/node_modules/[something2]/node_modules/[something3/.../.../node_modules/[somethingX]/
```

In this scenario a given [dependency] might be present on X levels under /usr/local/lib/node_modules.

My major concern is related to updating these modules. I do not find it hard to imagine to have concurrent modules of different versions installed at the same time.

Wouldn't it be easier to just put everything directly in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ and then cross-reference dependencies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is when mongoose is only coded to work with say v1 of mongodb, and you've coded your app to work with v2 of mongodb - as such, it installs and loads up both versions so it all works. We can do this easily in node, as the require module way doesn't pollute the global namespace, unlike the browser - which makes managing and including the right dependencies a royal pain due the global namespace pollution.

Now if your package.json and mongoose's package.json allow the same mongodb version (your can specify a specific version or ranges), then doing a `rm -Rf node_modules; npm install` will only install one copy of mongodb, rather than two. However as said before, if multiple versions are specified, multiple versions will be installed and loaded.

Comment: Doesn't this create a hectic hierarchy after having installed a bunch of different modules and having started a bunch of different projects?

Is there a way to run a recursive update with NPM?

Comment: Providing people are coding tiny modules that will one day be finished, rather than large modules that will always keep updating, only one copy of the module will be installed. So it turns out to not be that big of a problem in reality, as most of the node modules are tiny, and if not, they listen to substack (James Halliday - http://substack.net/) for a while, and then get convinced to adopt the tiny philosophy too :) A while ago I posted some thoughts on this exact issue here: https://gist.github.com/balupton/5308717 perhaps it will help, it took me ages to come around to this as well :)

Comment: `if [both]... allow the same [] version... will only install one copy `  Why doesn't it do that then?  I've got a particular case where only one copy should be used but several copies are being installed, and it's taking a really long time because... well I'm not sure why, but each instance takes quite a while to install!