# npm - how to avoid duplicate node module installation for my "sandbox"?

Tags: node.js, package, npm

I have a "Sandbox" directory to test various node repositories. Each repository comes with its own `package.json` that requires me to run `npm` to install its dependencies. That leads to the same dependency modules being installed again and again.

Is there a way to avoid this waste? 
Ideally I would like all modules required by `package.json` of each repository down the directory tree to be installed in the top "Sadbox" directory or skipped if it is aleady there.

So when I run `npm i` inside

```
Sandbox/repo1
```

it would check if a module from its `package.json` is already inside

```
Sandbox/node_modules/
```

and if yes and the version is compatible, it would skip that module.

I have tried to use `dedupe` but this doesn't seem to work this way.

Comment: Uh? how do you install those packages? `npm install package-name` will as well install all dependencies, all into your `node_modules`, do not run `npm install` inside of those packages again.

Comment: @alandarev Sorry I meant repositories, not packages, corrected now. These are repos downloaded from Github or created by Yeoman.

Comment: Any chance the depedencies these projects have differ? For example, they may both require *Express*, but different **versions**. If nobody helps by the evening, I will look closer to your issue, once I get machine with Node.js available.

Comment: @alandarev The may need different versions, in which case full installation is ok, but more often then not they don't. Thanks!

Comment: @dmitri Does symlinking not solve your problem?

Comment: @AndrásIványi Is there an automated way to use symlinks?

Comment: Run ln -s ../node_modules node_modules inside of your repo1, and it will stay there. What part do you want to automate?

Comment: @alandarev I was thinking of linking individual modules, not whole `node_modules` - is that a safe thing to do?

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev in the disaster case all you can lose is `node_modules`, which is not a great loss. Answering whether it is safe or not, I'd say the consequences are low, thus safe. I believe linking `node_modules` will not give any conflict unless you get version conflicts, then linking *some* might be better. But I would expect NPM to have a better method of handling this issue, than a need to create symlinks

Comment: @alandarev That is what I was thinking - is there NPM-native way of handling these issues (option to skip modules if they are already installed up the tree)?

Comment: Could not find anything in the documentation. I believe it might be on purpose, so that your child module does not depend on well-being of parent, what if parent decide to change something in `node_modules`, as a result the child will silently fail as it relied on correct versions/modules from parent. There is an overhead to pay in the price of space of course.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possiblities:

1: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders#cycles-conflicts-and-folder-parsimony

> At every stage, if a package is already installed in an ancestor node_modules folder, then it is not installed at the current location.

2: [npm config-variable 'link'](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#link):

> If true, then local installs will link if there is a suitable globally installed package.
>
> Note that this means that local installs can cause things to be installed into the global space at the same time. The link is only done if one of the two conditions are met:
>
> - The package is not already installed globally, or
> - the globally installed version is identical to the version that is being installed locally.

Comment: Although a package may not actually be installed multiple times, some packages still seems to go through some kind of install script resulting in really SLOW installs.

Comment: Is there a way to use `link` without it trying to install to the global space if my user doesn't have the required permissions?

Comment: seems like [`link` option](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/config#link) changed its meaning:  _Used with npm ls, limiting output to only those packages that are linked._

Answer (score 0):

The answer "[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15948590/893612)" mentions a way to avoid the duplicate downloads/install of the same package encountered in case of `npm install`.

Comment: It only said to remove and re-install the packages again, I don't see how this can solve the problem and skip the installation if the same package is already in the higher directory?